# Need to call a .Net Class library dll from a Classic ASP Page

Tags: .net, vbscript, asp-classic, com-interop, class-library

I need to call a .Net Class Library from a vbscript application
I have written a C# class library and created a COM DLL component and a type library file
I have successfully registered the dll and tlb on my local computer using

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe 
  "C:\user\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\[Sample]\[Sample]\bin\Debug\[Sample].dll" 
  /tlb "C:\user\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\[Sample]\[Sample]\bin\Debug\[Sample].tlb"
```

The dll and the type library file are registered successfully
I can see them in the windows registry

Now the issue is accessing it in an asp page:

```
<%@  Language=VBScript %>
<html> 
<body>
<%


dim cls
dim myDevelopmentDBConn

Set myDevelopmentDBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With myDevelopmentDBConn
.Provider = "SQLNCLI"
.ConnectionString = "user ID=abc;password=abc;Initial Catalog=TestLdb;Data         
 Source=sqlservername"
.ConnectionTimeout = 600
.CommandTimeout = 600
.Open
 End With
Response.Write  myDevelopmentDBConn
Set myDevelopmentDBConn =nothing
Set cls = Server.CreateObject("Sample.SqlJobs") 'SqlJobs is the name of the class 
Response.Write cls

'Response.Write "<b>" & cls.UpdateSqlJob("Test1","sqlservername", "abc", "abc" ) & "</b>"

'Test1=sqlserverjob name
'abc-username
'abc-password
Set cls =nothing
%>

</body>

</html>
```

When I run this file I got the following error

> The page cannot be displayed

I am getting an error

> Error Type:
>   Server object, ASP 0177 (0x80131522)
>   80131522
>   /testdll.asp, line 25
>   Set cls = Server.CreateObject("Sample.SqlJobs") //SqlJobs is the name of the class
>   This will be the line 25
>   The server Instance is not getting created

Can anyone please help me figure out where I am going wrong and suggest me possible ways of fixing this issue?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=113

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `/codebase` command line switch with `regasm` if your assembly is not installed into the GAC.

"...The Codebase entry specifies the file path for an assembly that is not installed in the global assembly cache..." - have a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more info